# printer driver type application

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, printers

I am working on a application which requires me to create a printer type driver, which offers to decrease the quality of document, and then prints the document.

Where document can be anything like image, word, pdf. And this application should be listed as new printer in the documents printers menu.

What I was thinking to create an application that will be installed as printer driver, and when this printer is selected for print then this application consider print documents as image and decrease the image quality based on user input. then these can be copied into new pdf and then print this newly created pdf silently using default printer drivers.

Can anyone tell me if I am thinking on the right track, and if I am thinking on right then please help me out in this, as I have no idea how to do this stuff.

I am using C# and .NET for creating this application.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a good approach but it's not possible to create a printer driver in C# and .NET.  You will need the Windows Driver Kit and C/C++.